# Simplifying an integrand

Tags: calculus

Could someone point to the location of my error in the following calculation?

I am trying to calculate $\int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{y} \sqrt{a-x^2}^{a-2} \sqrt{1+(L'(x))^2} \ dx$ where $L(x) = \sqrt{a-x^2}$. So, $$L'(x) = (1/2)(a-x^2)^{-1/2}(-2x)
\implies (L'(x))^2 = \frac{x^2}{a-x^2}.$$ Substituting into the integral gives, $$\int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{y} \sqrt{a-x^2}^{a-2} \sqrt{1 + x^2/(a-x^2)}=\int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{y} \sqrt{a-x^2}^{a-2}\sqrt{a/(a-x^2)}.$$ Simplifying gives, $$\sqrt{a}\int_{-\sqrt{a}}^y \sqrt{a-x^2}^{a-3},$$ though I know this isn't correct.

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know this isn't correct?

Comment: I was told that the solution could be written in terms of elementary functions, and I don't think this integral can. Perhaps I'm wrong. I've suppressed a constant involving n in front of the integral, but I don't think helps.